# Skipping more than one row in Python csv

Tags: python, csv

I am connecting to an API to snag some data. The output is a report that includes a multi-line header combined with a traditional single-line header.

Example:

```
1. Document Name: Test
2. Document Date: 8/7/2015
3. Document ID: 3804804
4. Document Author: Joe Blow
5.
6. Date, ID, Name, Age, Sex, Result
7. 8/7/2015, 2808380, Sara Jenkings, 33, F, 208.20
```

In the example, I want to skip over lines 1 - 5 and write the row on line 6 as the header row and all other rows after that as normal rows.

Now, I know how to skip over one line with `next(reader, None)`, but how do I skip more than one row if I know the number of rows to skip will be consistently 5 rows like in the example?

I normally would use a database to skip the rows, but I want to see if I can have Python save the data correctly without the database doing more work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), passing the line you want to begin writing from as the second parameter so for line 6 being 0 based you use `5`, *If stop is None, then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted*

```
import  csv

from itertools import islice

with open("in.csv") as f, open("out.csv","w") as out:
    r = csv.reader(islice(f, start=5,stop=None))
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    wr.writerows(r)
```

You don't necessarily need the csv module if you are keeping the lines as is:

```
with open("in.csv") as f, open("out.csv","w") as out:
    r = islice(f, 5 ,None)
    out.writelines(r)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to save the output to a csv file and then create another file to input the islice output as the cleaned csv file. It worked perfectly without the csv module as the data is already in csv format from the stream. But, is there a way to use islice with the streamed data or do I always have to output the data to a csv (in.csv) and run that file through islice?

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: The data is from an API (HTTP request via Python I believe).

Comment: You can also write to a tempfile and slice that instead of writing to disk or a StringIO object

Comment: Would that be recommended vs tempfile or in-memory?

Comment: Ahh, can dump into StringIO and then free the memory. But, if the data is greater than the memory, I'm screwed. I guess I'll leave it as is and create a IN file for each stream and then the final file is the OUT. Keep it simple.

Comment: @Fastidious, if you do it in memory you just have to .seek(0) on the tempfile object and then write the file using islice. You could also probably call islice on the stream object itself and forget any intermediate file object. What exactly does the api return?

Comment: When I did a Type() on the call I constructed to pull the data, Python says it's a STR. When i used the other solution below this one with COUNT < 5, it only counts the number of characters in the return. So, seems like it's a returned string.

Comment: can you link to the api, it will be easier to see what it is if I can see the source?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a counter and an if statement to a for loop.

```
count = 0
for line in opened_file:
    if count < 5:
        count += 1
        continue
    #Parse lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Skipping 5 header lines using list comprehension:

```
import csv

nheaderlines = 5

with open(path + file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    [next(reader, None) for item in range(nheaderlines)]

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```